# What's the adventages and disadventages of reducing states in state space model? - Model reduction

Tags: systems-of-equations, matlab, control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filter

In control theory, there is something called "Model reduction". That's means states from a state space model decreasing.

I know that's a small state space model, is much easier to model, that a large state space model.

For exampel. If I want to build a LQGI (Linear Quadratic Gaussian Integral) controller with analog electrical compontens such as several operation amplifiers, resistors and capacitors. It will requires a lot of those if the state space model is large.

**So my question is:**
Can I still have an optimal controller, even if I reducing a lot of states? Or do I lose some optimal properties just by "removing" som states?

I would like to build a LQGI controller with only analog electrical components because that controller will then work in real-time, like a digital controller would not do, due to the sampling time.

Comment: What sampling time are we talking about? 10 Hz? 100 Hz? 1 kHz? 10 kHz? 100 kHz? 1 MHz? "Or do I lose some optimal properties just by "removing" som states?" And of course you do. Furthermore, how "big" is your state space model? How many states/differential equations?

Comment: Let's say 6x6 A matrix.

Comment: Applying model reduction on a 6x6 system is not worth it in my opinion. My guess is, is that you will loose to much information of the system. However,you can check that by the singular values to check how dominant each pole/eigenvalue is. If they are not dominant you could through them away without loosing to much information of your system. But in general you only apply model reduction on systems which have hundreds of states. And the reason you do that is because of the computational load. Personally I would not bother to apply it for any system which does not have more then 25 states.

Comment: Thank you. My control systems is nerver more that 10x10